# QueryParser short cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, apache, lucene

i have some indexed docs and i wanna search in them using a query, i checked lucene documentation and made this code but somehow im getting "short cannot be dereferenced" in the QueryParser line, Im new to Java and to Lucene, im using Lucene 5.3.1

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.time.Clock.system;
import javax.management.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer;

import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;

import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import static sun.rmi.transport.TransportConstants.Version;
import static sun.rmi.transport.TransportConstants.Version;




public class Searcher
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        String  query="computer science";
        Analyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
         Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "W", analyzer).parse(query); //ERROR IS HERE

         Path indexPath = Paths.get("MonIndex");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath);
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher iSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopDocs topdocs = iSearcher.search(q2, 100);
        ScoreDoc[] resultsList = topdocs.scoreDocs;
         for(int i = 0; i<resultsList.length; i++){
             Document book = iSearcher.doc(resultsList[i].doc); 
             System.out.println(book.getField("I").stringValue());
         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `Version.LUCENE_CURRENT`. You are not importing Lucene's `Version`, but you do have `sun.rmi.transport.TransportConstants.Version`, which, while I'm not familiar with the library, it certainly [does appear to be a short](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/rmi/transport/TransportConstants.java#TransportConstants.0Version). So attempting to dereference that, by attempting to reference the nonexistent `sun.rmi.transport.TransportConstants.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT` is causing that error to be thrown.

However, in the version of Lucene you say you are using, [the `QueryParser`ctor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html#QueryParser(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer)) no longer even accepts a Version argument, so just remove it:

```
Query q = new QueryParser("W", analyzer).parse(query);
```

---

Your next error: The `Query` that the queryparser returns is not a `javax.management.Query`.

Comment: I dont have any error but it doesnt print anything x)

Comment: @lefragan - Sure, that would be expected in the event that the query matches 0 results...

Comment: What im i doin wrong ? i need to use javax Query and not Lucene's Query?

Comment: If you are not trying to work [MBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html), then you should *not* be importing `javax.management.Query`. As far as why you aren't getting results, I don't know what you have indexed, and so can't help you there.

Comment: I indexed some documents, each document has and identifier **I** a title **T** a resume **W**, some references **X** and authors **A**, indexation works and i tried to work witouth QueryParser before, to search for single terms and it worked great, but when trying to use QueryParser.. x))) Thank you for you time btw

Comment: Even now if the query="computer" it works but when i try to do an OR query="computer|science" it doesnt work

Comment: Okay, couple of things: 1- `KeywordAnalyzer` is almost certainly the wrong choice. It basically does no analysis. Use the same analyzer as you did when indexing. 2- You aren't actually searching with the Query returned from the QueryParser in your code. You generate it, then just use a FuzzyQuery instead.  So: change the analyzer and lose the FuzzyQuery.

Comment: With the right analyzer, that query would effectively be an or query, but the character `|` is not a part of Lucene's query syntax. Using the right analyzer is key.

Comment: I should use a boolean query for OR operators ?

Comment: You could, but you should also read up on the query parser syntax: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview

Comment: Aw greaaat !! Thank you mate, i know my questions are a bit stupid for you but im Newbie in Lucene x) Thank you for your time